# setting Jekyll_env to Production

Tags: jenkins, jekyll

Accordingly to the documentation in order to provide the "production" flag to Jekyll the command must be run like this:

```
$ JEKYLL_ENV=production jekyll build
```

The command works great, but I am trying to run it through Jenkins and in order for it to work on Jenkins I need to use the following

```
$ C:\Ruby24-x64\bin\jekyll build
```

Unfortunately I cant prefix the command as such

```
$ JEKYLL_ENV=production C:\Ruby24-x64\bin\jekyll build
```

else it will fail, I have also tried the following

```
$ SET JEKYLL_ENV=production
$ C:\Ruby24-x64\bin\jekyll build
```

But the JEKYLL_ENV variable is not set. Does anyone have an idea on how to run this command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up giving up on this given my particular situation and I am instead using config.yml files for the environment option, yes I wont use JEKYLL_ENV but the code runs and I am able to produce the outcome as expected on different environments. In case some one runs into this issue and would like a quick alternative.

Comment: Yep. I am giving up on this too. I think it was implemented and/or documented poorly. I don't know if it is because I am on windows or some other reason, but I can't seem to set it when building with bundler or jekyll directly. Remains `development`or breaks - using the documented commands and variants. I'll use different 'environmental' config files and declare a `site.environment` variable and instead. Frustrating!